# More than 2 levels in bullet points

Tags: support

In a number of questions, I've found the need to use 3-4 levels in bullet points (ex: [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/what-is-the-most-effective-healing-class-in-dd-4e/5122#5122)).

Would it be possible to request the devs implement arbitrary nesting of unordered and ordered lists?

```
* Level 1
 * Level 2
  * Level 3  (should be)
   * Level 4 (nope, not working)
 * Level 2 again
```

- Level 1

  - Level 2
  - Level 3  (should be)
  - Level 4 (nope, not working)
  - Level 2 again

Comment: +1 I have the same problem a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use 3 spaces for each succeeding level.

- Level 1

  - Level 2

    - Level 3

      1. Level 4 (ordered)
      2. Level 4 again
  - Level 2 again

Comment: Oh. ... thanks. :)